# "With friends" facebook post wall

Tags: ruby, facebook, koala

I wonder is possible post on wall and add some friends to this.
I have a picture wich I have to upload and tags user's friends to that.

This is what I use to upload a photo using Koala gem in Ruby:

```
@graph.put_picture(@photo.image.path, 'image/png', { 
    :message => "Hello" 
})
```

This upload the photo and post in the wall with the message given.
I have to show a picture and tag friends, so I can both post on wall or upload the picture.

PS: It doesn't need to be in Ruby neither using Koala gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tags = {{:to => user_id, :tag_text => "tag text test", :x => x_coordinate, :y => y_coordinate},{#another tag...}}

@graph.put_picture(@photo.image.path, 'image/png', { 
    :message => "Hello" 
    :tags => tags
})
```

Where `user_id` would be the ID of the user you want to tag, `x_coordinate` would be the x axis coordinate where the tag should be located in the picture, and `y_coordinate` would be the same for the y axis.